# ¿Cómo puedo gestionar los clientes de un servidor Linda?

Tags: c#

mi pregunta es la siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con un servidor basado en Linda, un sistema de sincronización asíncrona. Y mi duda surge al querer gestionar los servidores que estan en espera del recurso que quieren. Ya que no se cómo notificar a un cliente en concreto de que lo que queria ha llegado y no al resto tambien.

Comment: Hola, tal y como está redactada la pregunta parece algo amplia y no termina de quedar claro lo que quieres. Trata de añadir algo más de información: ¿qué has investigado? ¿has intentado algo? ¿con qué problemas/dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.